# There is a Runtime error "storage has wrong size:" when I use torch.load

Tags: load, torch

I get "RuntimeError storage has wrong size" when I'm invoking `torch.load("pthfilename")`. My model is trained on multiple GPUs and I saved the model using the following code:

```py
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7"
device = torch.device(arg.local_rank)
net = Net().to(device)
net = torch.nn.parallel.DistributedDataParallel(net, device_ids=[arg.local_rank])
torch.save(net.state_dict(), "0.pth"))
```

And the error is :

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/test.py", line 8, in <module>
    model_dict = torch.load("0.pth")
  File "torch/serialization.py", line 529, in load
    return _legacy_load(opened_file, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
  File "torch/serialization.py", line 709, in _legacy_load
    deserialized_objects[key]._set_from_file(f, offset, f_should_read_directly)
RuntimeError: storage has wrong size: expected -4916312287391674656 got 24
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use multiple processes type (like: DistributedDataParallel) train your model, you should assign a local_rank when you save your model.

[refer this link](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/runtimeerror-storage-has-wrong-size/88109), [this](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/e7870c1fd4706174f52a796521382c9342d4373f/imagenet/main.py#L254-L255) and [this](https://www.gushiciku.cn/pl/p7XP) , hope this solution could help you.

```
def save_checkpoint(epoch, model, best_top5, optimizer, 
                        is_best=False, 
                        filename='checkpoint.pth.tar'):
    state = {
        'epoch': epoch+1, 'state_dict': model.state_dict(),
        'best_top5': best_top5, 'optimizer' : optimizer.state_dict(),
    }
    torch.save(state, filename)

if args.local_rank == 0:
    if is_best: save_checkpoint(epoch, model, best_top5, optimizer, is_best=True, filename='model_best.pth.tar')
```